# Mysterious garbage character - IE 8 only

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8, trim, innertext

I am building a table, with content pulled from other elements in the page (page scraping).

I am using innerText or textContent to pull the text, then a regular expression to trim it:

```
string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```

This works fine in IE 9 and Chrome, but in IE 8 I am getting a garbage character that I cannot identify. I was able to reproduce the behavior with alerts in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Te4FQ/

What is this extra character, and how can I get rid of it?

Update: thanks for the helpful replies! It seems that the character in question is u200E (left to right mark). So the second part of my question remains, how can I get rid of such characters with regular expressions, and just keep regular text?

Comment: That works just fine for me with IE9 in IE8 browser mode. What character do you get?

Comment: You can use [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to identify the mysterious character.

Comment: Repros in IE7.  This appears to be character 8206, which is a left-to-right marker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the "At Risk" and "Complete" `<th>` tags in your jsFiddle snippet have a U+200E (Left-to-Right Mark, aka LRM) code point at the end of their content. That is not a whitespace character, so it cannot be matched by `\s`.

One way to get rid of this character is to use the [XRegExp library](http://xregexp.com/), so that you can replace all matches of `\p{C}` with the empty string (i.e., delete them). `\p{C}` matches any code point in Unicode's "Other" category, which includes control, format, private use, surrogate, and unassigned code points. U+200E, specifically, is within the `\p{Cf}` "Other, Format" subcategory.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how to express \p{C} in JavaScript regex? Using the library would be too heavy for my simple needs.

Comment: To accurately reproduce `\p{C}` on your own, based on the Unicode 6.1 Basic Multilingual Plane, you would need to use a regex character class more than 3,800 characters long. That assumes you take full advantage of code point ranges.

Comment: I am now using a negated POSIX print and it seems to work for my needs. The regex: /[^\x20-\x7E]/g

Answer (score 1):

Try printing to the page the result of

```
escape(string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""));
```

Your garbage character should show up as an escape code.

Comment: Thanks! Any regex technique to recommend, that would take care of such garbage characters? It seems that \s doesn't work.